# Assuming pointer as a struct

Tags: c++

I remember on MASM32 compiler the directive ASSUME that let me assume a pointer as a struct. Is any way to do this in C++? For example I want to do this:

```
char* test = new char [sizeof MyStruct + MAX_REALIGN];
MyStruct* data = test;
data.member = 1;
```

The reason I need this is because I have a pointer to a struct which I need to recompile with new data, increasing the size of the original struct and realign some of their members. After the recompile is done I will no longer reference to the new struct, I just need the reference before making the recompile.

It sounds a little hard to understand, but the question is quite simple: is there any way to reference a pointer as a struct? (I know its not safe, portable, etc, etc).

Comment: It's hard to understand because you're not using proper terminology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert char pointer (char*) to struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616845/convert-char-pointer-char-to-struct)

Comment: And what would be the terminology for reference a pointer as an struct for re align it, in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinterpret_cast converts any pointer type to any other pointer type, even of unrelated classes.

Answer (score 0):

`MyStruct* data = reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(test);`

Alternatively, you can use a c-style cast, which is functionally equivalent in this case.

`MyStruct* data = (MyStruct*)test;`

This is [generally dis-recommended](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP05-CPP.+Do+not+use+C-style+casts) because the c-style casts coerce the value into whatever you say. However, that's basically what you're doing with the reinterpret-cast, so the cleaner syntax may be worth it (though I'd question why you're doing it this way to begin with).

Comment: I always use C style... Why bother writing so long?

Comment: The link in my answer explains it a bit, you could also look into it. The short of it is that the c++ style casts will throw compiler errors if you're doing something dangerous inadvertently.